# Is watching a video where someone is wearing a tattoo haram

Tags: halal-haram, sin, doubts

I saw this YouTube channel I like it but the person is wearing a tattoo and I want to know if this is ok to watch (no music in his channel) and no I don’t wear tattoos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not haram. Having tattoo or drawing tattoo for others is prohibited not watching people who have tattoos. Then what about people who worship others other than Allah. That is worse than having a tattoo.

You can talk and see people who are non-muslims, so you can also see people who has tattoos.